# Linter (eslint) keep errors after fix them in Nuxt app

Tags: eslint, nuxt.js

I'm building an app with nuxt (v2.1.0)

Linter is working fine sometimes.
However, most of the time, after I have fixed the linter error, I'm still having the error and if I want to continue I need to restart the process.

Any idea why? It's a little bit annoying

- I have a macOS (High Sierra)
- Tried with both `npm` and `yarn`
- Node v9.

Regards,
Jorge

Comment: that shouldnt happen. there is bug when error in console dont disappear -> https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3970 but it affect only console